# How do I add images to cascading selects dynamically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project where I need to make cascading selects that dynamically change based on what the user selects. This small website, when visited, will prompt the user to select one of two consoles, and then, based off of that, to select a color for said console, and then to choose a game that comes with it. Here is the current JS and HTML I have:

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cascading Selects</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Console Picker/Store</h2>

        <div id="selectsDiv">
        </div>
        <script src="selectData.js"></script>
        <script src="createSelects.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS creating the selects:

```
    let selectsDiv = document.getElementById("selectsDiv");

    let consoleSelect = document.createElement('select');
    consoleSelect.setAttribute("id", "console");
    consoleSelect.options.add(new Option('-- Select a Console --', 'console')); //new Option(text, value) 
    selectsDiv.appendChild(consoleSelect);

    let colorSelect = document.createElement('select');
    colorSelect.setAttribute("id", "color");
    colorSelect.options.add(new Option('-- Select a Color --', 'color'));
    selectsDiv.appendChild(colorSelect);

    let gameSelect = document.createElement('select');
    gameSelect.setAttribute("id", "game");
    gameSelect.options.add(new Option('-- Select a Game --', 'game'));
    selectsDiv.appendChild(gameSelect);


    for (let console in selectData) { //for...in iterates over object properties        
        consoleSelect.options.add(new Option(console, console)); //new Option(text, value) 
    }
    

    consoleSelect.onchange = function () {
        // remove previous options from depending selects
        colorSelect.length = 1;
        gameSelect.length = 1;
        // add options to the depending select based on the current select value
        for (let color in selectData[this.value]) {
            colorSelect.options.add(new Option(color, color));
        }
    };

    colorSelect.onchange = function () {
        // remove previous options from depending selects
        gameSelect.length = 1;
        for (let game in selectData[this.previousElementSibling.value][this.value]) {
            gameSelect.options.add(new Option(game, game));
        }
    };


};
```

JS the data within the selects:

```
const selectData = {//JS Object which properties are strings
    "Nintendo Switch": {
        "Blue-Red Version": {
            "Pokemon Sword": 0,
            "Pokemon Shield": 0
        },
        "Gray-Black Version": {
            "Legend of Zelda: Breath of The Wild": 0,
            "Super Smash Bros. Ultimate": 0,
        }
    },
    "PlayStation 5": {
        "Digital Version (White)": {
            "Marvel's Spider-Man: Miles Morales (Digital Download)": 0
        },
        "Disc Version (White)": {
            "Demon's Souls: Remake": 0
        }
    }
};
```

My question is, when someone clicks on "Nintendo Switch" for example, how can I have an image of the Switch show up dynamically under the select box on the page? And so on and so forth change that image dynamically based on further selects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to create a `consoles` object, containing the name of the console as the object key and the value to the path url for your console picture.
Then once done that, you change the src of the image element based on the value of the `select dropdown`

If you check Playstation5 console you'll see that images don't change, but that's just a matter of updating your `consoles` object

```js
const consoles = {
 "Nintendo Switch": { 
     "picture" : "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/63acf0/fff&text=Nintendo Switch",
    "Blue-Red Version": {
      "picture" : "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/63acf0/fff&text=Nintendo Switch - Blue Red Version",
      "Pokemon Sword": {
        "picture" : "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/63acf0/fff&text=Nintendo Switch - Blue Red Version - Pokemon Sword",
      },
      "Pokemon Shield": {
        "picture" : "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/63acf0/fff&text=Nintendo Switch - Blue Red Version - Pokemon Shield",
      }
    },
    "Gray-Black Version": {
      "picture" : "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/63acf0/fff&text=Nintendo Switch - Gray-Black Version",
      "Legend of Zelda: Breath of The Wild": {
        "picture" : "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/63acf0/fff&text=Nintendo Switch - Gray-Black Version - Legend of Zelda: Breath of The Wild",
      },
      "Super Smash Bros. Ultimate": {
        "picture" : "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/63acf0/fff&text=Nintendo Switch",
      }
    }
 },
 "PlayStation 5": { 
     "picture" : "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/63acf0/fff&text=Playstation 5",
    "Digital Version (White)": {
      "picture" : "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/63acf0/fff&text=Playstation 5",
      "Marvel's Spider-Man: Miles Morales (Digital Download)": {
        "picture" : "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/63acf0/fff&text=Playstation 5",
      }
    },
    "Disc Version (White)": {
      "picture" : "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/63acf0/fff&text=Playstation 5",
      "Demon's Souls: Remake": {
        "picture" : "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/63acf0/fff&text=Playstation 5",
      }
    }
 },
}
const selectData = {//JS Object which properties are strings
    "Nintendo Switch": {
        "Blue-Red Version": {
            "Pokemon Sword": 0,
            "Pokemon Shield": 0
        },
        "Gray-Black Version": {
            "Legend of Zelda: Breath of The Wild": 0,
            "Super Smash Bros. Ultimate": 0,
        }
    },
    "PlayStation 5": {
        "Digital Version (White)": {
            "Marvel's Spider-Man: Miles Morales (Digital Download)": 0
        },
        "Disc Version (White)": {
            "Demon's Souls: Remake": 0
        }
    }
};

let selectedConsole, selectedColor, selectedGame;

let consolePicture = document.getElementById("consolePicture");
let selectsDiv = document.getElementById("selectsDiv");

let consoleSelect = document.createElement('select');
consoleSelect.setAttribute("id", "console");
consoleSelect.options.add(new Option('-- Select a Console --', 'console')); //new Option(text, value) 
selectsDiv.appendChild(consoleSelect);

let colorSelect = document.createElement('select');
colorSelect.setAttribute("id", "color");
colorSelect.options.add(new Option('-- Select a Color --', 'color'));
selectsDiv.appendChild(colorSelect);

let gameSelect = document.createElement('select');
gameSelect.setAttribute("id", "game");
gameSelect.options.add(new Option('-- Select a Game --', 'game'));
selectsDiv.appendChild(gameSelect);


for (let console in selectData) { //for...in iterates over object properties        
  consoleSelect.options.add(new Option(console, console)); //new Option(text, value) 
}

function setPicture(picture) {
 consolePicture.src = picture;
}

consoleSelect.onchange = function () {
  // remove previous options from depending selects
  colorSelect.length = 1;
  gameSelect.length = 1;
  // add options to the depending select based on the current select value
  for (let color in selectData[this.value]) {
    colorSelect.options.add(new Option(color, color));
  }
  selectedConsole = consoles[this.value];
  setPicture(selectedConsole.picture)
};

colorSelect.onchange = function () {
  // remove previous options from depending selects
  gameSelect.length = 1;
  for (let game in selectData[this.previousElementSibling.value][this.value]) {
    gameSelect.options.add(new Option(game, game));
  }
  
  selectedColor = selectedConsole[this.value];
  setPicture(selectedColor.picture)
}

gameSelect.onchange = function() { 
    selectedGame = selectedColor[this.value]
  setPicture(selectedGame.picture)
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cascading Selects</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Console Picker/Store</h2>

        <div id="selectsDiv">
        </div>
        <img id="consolePicture" />
        <script src="selectData.js"></script>
        <script src="createSelects.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This works for consoleSelect.onchange and I've adapted it to work for colorSelect.onchange. However, i cannot figure out how to implement this solution for when the user wishes to click the game they wish to select. I've created this a gameselect.onchange, with a method named setGamePic, which works in a similar fashion to what you've written above, but how do I adapt it to work with this code? The issue is that setting the console picture is done within the console select function, colorselect within its funmctin, but I have no gameselect function.

Comment: how to add link to image in this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an argument to the callback function assigned to the `onchange` event that has a property called `target` which is a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched which is here an option that has a value

```js
const selectData = {
  //JS Object which properties are strings
  "Nintendo Switch": {
    "Blue-Red Version": {
      "Pokemon Sword": 0,
      "Pokemon Shield": 0,
    },
    "Gray-Black Version": {
      "Legend of Zelda: Breath of The Wild": 0,
      "Super Smash Bros. Ultimate": 0,
    },
  },
  "PlayStation 5": {
    "Digital Version (White)": {
      "Marvel's Spider-Man: Miles Morales (Digital Download)": 0,
    },
    "Disc Version (White)": {
      "Demon's Souls: Remake": 0,
    },
  },
};




let selectsDiv = document.getElementById("selectsDiv");

let consoleSelect = document.createElement("select");
consoleSelect.setAttribute("id", "console");
consoleSelect.options.add(new Option("-- Select a Console --", "console")); //new Option(text, value)
selectsDiv.appendChild(consoleSelect);

let colorSelect = document.createElement("select");
colorSelect.setAttribute("id", "color");
colorSelect.options.add(new Option("-- Select a Color --", "color"));
selectsDiv.appendChild(colorSelect);

let gameSelect = document.createElement("select");
gameSelect.setAttribute("id", "game");
gameSelect.options.add(new Option("-- Select a Game --", "game"));
selectsDiv.appendChild(gameSelect);

for (let console in selectData) {
  //for...in iterates over object properties
  consoleSelect.options.add(new Option(console, console)); //new Option(text, value)
}

consoleSelect.onchange = function (e) {
  // remove previous options from depending selects
  colorSelect.length = 1;
  gameSelect.length = 1;
  // add options to the depending select based on the current select value
  for (let color in selectData[this.value]) {
    colorSelect.options.add(new Option(color, color));
  }
  
  if (e.target.value === 'Nintendo Switch') {
    console.log('Nintendo Switch selected');
  } else if (e.target.value === 'PlayStation 5') {
    console.log('PlayStation 5 selected');
  }
};

colorSelect.onchange = function () {
  // remove previous options from depending selects
  gameSelect.length = 1;
  for (let game in selectData[this.previousElementSibling.value][this.value]) {
    gameSelect.options.add(new Option(game, game));
  }
};
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cascading Selects</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Console Picker/Store</h2>

    <div id="selectsDiv"></div>
    <script src="selectData.js"></script>
    <script src="createSelects.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```